# bootstrap button size without changing the size of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put login button on navbar, but as soon as I put it on navbar the size of navbar increases. how do I prevent the navbar changing the size and change the size of button?

```
<div class="navbar-primary">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="/accounts/signin/">login</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Here I want to replace the word login with a bootstrap button, I've tried putting `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>`
 inside but navbar size changes because of the size of button

Edit:

[register](/accounts/signup/)

[login[image]](/accounts/signin/)

Comment: Surely a bigger button requires a larger navbar? Otherwise it will overflow it. Or is that what you're after?

Comment: no trying to decrease the size of button, and control margin as well so it fits navbar nicely

Comment: Have you tried the `btn-sm` class?

Comment: yes first thing I've tried, it changes the size of navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a simple solution just add this selector and styles

```css
.btn-sm {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is a link to a codepen with the exact code except with the styles that I provided

[Example](http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/jWwPYG)

You can add and remove the styles to see the difference.

And in case you want the navbar to be a little bit bigger just add to the padding-top and padding-bottom accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but why does it change the margin between other buttons as well? I have one more button next to login and the distance between them got increased

Comment: Ok I added an exact button to the codepen and I just added  padding-left: 0px; and the distance between them decreased.

Comment: It still looks so weird, there's space between two buttons....maybe I should use span?

Comment: Let me edit test a bit with the codepen. Do you mind a difference of the left and right margins?     I just added margin-left: -10px; and it also decreased the length between the two spaces

Comment: I uploaded the picture of the buttons, there are margin between them which look weird ^^

Comment: I added negative margins

Comment: I don't see it? ohh I've never heard negative margins..anyway I don't see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100332/discussion-between-kim-kimm-and-htmlnoob).